# Testing Spring managed servlet

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-test

I need to test a servlet, which is working fine now.

The servlet needs to use a Spring service, so it is modified for that this way:

```
SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnServletContext(
    this, config.getServletContext()); // ImageServlet.java line 49
```

After migration to Spring 4, the test broke and currently it throws this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException:
No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.
    getRequiredWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:84)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.
    processInjectionBasedOnServletContext(SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.java:107)
at package.ImageServlet.init(ImageServlet.java:49)
at in.nasv.utils.ImageServletTest.accessingImageViaHttp(ImageServletTest.java:45)
```

Here is the portion of code of ImageServletTest:

```
// prepare servlet instance
MockServletConfig config = new MockServletConfig(
    new MockServletContextPatched());
ImageServlet servlet = new ImageServlet();
servlet.init( config ); // ImageServletTest, line 45
```

And this patched class (is not actually patched now):

```
public class MockServletContextPatched extends MockServletContext{ }
```

What am I supposed to do to avoid this "IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?" ?

Comment: Do you actually need to invoke the `init()` method to test your Servlet? If not, I'd recommend you just instantiate your Servlet and _inject_ its dependencies manually instead of relying on `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport` in your test.

Comment: Great approach, but it is not applicable for my case.   Spring MockServletContext has very limited functionality (no setters and getters return only fixed values, dummy Spring!) so I need to extend it. I could apply it only via init()

Comment: Spring's `MockServletContext` **does** have setters. What do you consider limitations in Spring's `MockServletContext`? What is special about your custom `MockServletContextPatched`?

Comment: I needed setter for MimeType, but only getter exists. My MockServletContextPatched extends this. Yes, MockServletContext has 3 additional setters, but many other have not - limited functionality for the mock class of Spring.

Comment: There is no setter method in `MockServletContext` for the MIME type since Spring uses the Java Activation Framework to resolve the MIME type for the file name passed into `getMimeType(String)`. If you would need a means for setting a custom MIME type that is not supported by the Java Activation Framework, please create a new JIRA issue against the 'Spring Framework' project and 'Test' component to request that feature.

Comment: I don't know about "Java Activation Framework", but the idea of fakes, mocks and other test double is to provide some fake data to the other part of the system. Avoiding such basic functionality seems funny to me. I will not feature request this, because the communication for it will be much more that the real fix for it. And because this is Spring has numerous critical limitations, mess-ups and incomprehensible error responses, much more critical than this.

Comment: With the Java Activation Framework, you *can* configure fake data. So Spring is definitely not _avoiding such basic functionality_. I will describe the correct approach in the form of an _answer_.

Answer (score 0):

I found an solution. But clear enough, but an solution.

Now servlet initialization is:

```
MockServletContext servletContext = new MockServletContextPatched();
MockServletConfig config = new MockServletConfig( servletContext );
ImageServlet servlet = new ImageServlet();

ClassPathXmlApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext( "spring-data-app-context.xml" );
DefaultListableBeanFactory dlbf = new DefaultListableBeanFactory(appContext.getBeanFactory());
GenericWebApplicationContext gwac = new GenericWebApplicationContext(dlbf);        
servletContext.setAttribute(GenericWebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE, gwac);
gwac.setServletContext(servletContext);
gwac.refresh();

servlet.init( config );
```

Preparing request and response in standard way:

```
MockHttpServletResponse response = new MockHttpServletResponse();

URL serverUrl = new URL( propertyExtendedService.getServerAddress(true) );
MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
request.setRequestURI( "/what-you-want" );
request.setPathInfo( "/" + TEST_IMAGE );
request.setContentType("image/jpeg");
request.addHeader("Accept", "image/jpeg;image/jpg;" );
```

Final step is to call the filter and assert returned values:

```
servlet.doGet( request, response );
assertEquals( response.getStatus(), 200 );
// assert everything you want
```

Comment: You definitely should not be loading two `ApplicationContext`s. One is sufficient. Furthermore, the _Spring TestContext Framework_ already sets up the testing infrastructure for a `WebApplicationContext` for you (including a `MockServletContext`, `MockHttpServletRequest`, and `MockHttpServletResponse`). Have you had a look at that?

Comment: See [Loading a WebApplicationContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-web) and [Testing request and session scoped beans](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-web-scoped-beans) for details.

Answer (score 0):

*Update*: the [updated documentation for `getServletContext()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockServletContext.html#getMimeType-java.lang.String-) is now online.

---

It is not necessary to implement a custom `MockServletContextPatched` class just to configure a custom MIME type in Spring's `MockServletContext`.

Since Spring's `MockServletContext` uses the Java Activation Framework (JAF) to implement the `ServletContext.getMimeType(String)` method, it is quite easy to configure a custom MIME type via JAF's `MimetypesFileTypeMap.addMimeTypes(String)` method as follows.

```
MockServletContext mockServletContext = new MockServletContext();
MimetypesFileTypeMap mimetypesFileTypeMap =
    (MimetypesFileTypeMap) MimetypesFileTypeMap.getDefaultFileTypeMap();
mimetypesFileTypeMap.addMimeTypes("text/enigma    enigma");
assertEquals("text/enigma", mockServletContext.getMimeType("filename.enigma"));
```

In the above JUnit based test code, I configured a custom MIME type `"text/enigma"` for files that have the extension `.enigma`.

Hope this helps!

Regards,

Sam (author of the Spring TestContext Framework)

p.s. I created JIRA issue [SPR-12126](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12126) in order to improve the documentation of `MockServletContext`.

Comment: Hi Sam. Thanks for the solution for my workaround. Sorry, but I dropped this test (all old servlet functionality was dropped, so its test was also dropped), so I could test it. Your approach seems to be an elegant approach. But...

Comment: But I am not sure whether it is better. Most of developers will look for a setter because common test doubles are simple and with hardcoded values. Other reason is that JAF seems to be not commonly known, so may be MimetypesFileTypeMap will be skipped. But this is my opinion, I way be wrong. Again 10x for the solution.